# Java: Combining JSpinners, Event Listeners, and Text Fields

Tags: java, swing

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
public class guiStatDistribution2 extends JFrame {

int str = 1;
int dex = 1;
int intel = 1;
int con = 1;
int cha = 1;
int remainingPoints = 45;

JTextField remainingDisplay = new JTextField("You have " + remainingPoints + " points left to distribute.");

SpinnerNumberModel strPoints = new SpinnerNumberModel(1,1,46,1);
SpinnerNumberModel dexPoints = new SpinnerNumberModel(1,1,46,1);
SpinnerNumberModel intPoints = new SpinnerNumberModel(1,1,46,1);
SpinnerNumberModel conPoints = new SpinnerNumberModel(1,1,46,1);
SpinnerNumberModel chaPoints = new SpinnerNumberModel(1,1,46,1);



public guiStatDistribution2() {

    JSpinner strSpin = new JSpinner(strPoints);
    JSpinner dexSpin = new JSpinner(dexPoints);
    JSpinner intSpin = new JSpinner(intPoints);
    JSpinner conSpin = new JSpinner(conPoints);
    JSpinner chaSpin = new JSpinner(chaPoints);
    //instance for strength
    strSpin.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            if (remainingPoints != 0) {
                str = strPoints.getNumber().intValue();
                remainingPoints = (remainingPoints - (str-1) - (dex-1) - (intel-1) - (con-1) - (cha-1));
                remainingDisplay.revalidate();
            }
            if (remainingPoints == 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No points left. Lower another score to add more.");
            }
        }
    });
    //instance for dexterity
    dexSpin.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent f) {
            if (remainingPoints != 0) {
                dex = dexPoints.getNumber().intValue();
                remainingPoints = (remainingPoints - (str-1) - (dex-1) - (intel-1) - (con-1) - (cha-1));
                remainingDisplay.revalidate();
            }
            if (remainingPoints == 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No points left. Lower another score to add more.");
            }
        }
    });
    //instance for intelligence
    intSpin.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent g) {
            if (remainingPoints != 0) {
                intel = intPoints.getNumber().intValue();
                remainingPoints = (remainingPoints - (str-1) - (dex-1) - (intel-1) - (con-1) - (cha-1));
                remainingDisplay.revalidate();
            }
            if (remainingPoints == 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No points left. Lower another score to add more.");
            }
        }
    });
    //instance for constitution
    conSpin.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent h) {
            if (remainingPoints != 0) {
                con = conPoints.getNumber().intValue();
                remainingPoints = (remainingPoints - (str-1) - (dex-1) - (intel-1) - (con-1) - (cha-1));
                remainingDisplay.revalidate();
            }
            if (remainingPoints == 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No points left. Lower another score to add more.");
            }
        }
    });
    //instance for charisma
    chaSpin.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent i) {
            if (remainingPoints != 0) {
                cha = chaPoints.getNumber().intValue();
                remainingPoints = (remainingPoints - (str-1) - (dex-1) - (intel-1) - (con-1) - (cha-1));
                remainingDisplay.revalidate();
            }
            if (remainingPoints == 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No points left. Lower another score to add more.");
            }
        }
    });

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,0,5));
    p1.add(new JTextField("Strength: "));
    p1.add(strSpin);

    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,0,5));
    p2.add(new JTextField("Dexterity: "));
    p2.add(dexSpin);

    JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
    p3.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,0,5));
    p3.add(new JTextField("Intelligence: "));
    p3.add(intSpin);

    JPanel p4 = new JPanel();
    p4.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,0,5));
    p4.add(new JTextField("Constitution: "));
    p4.add(conSpin);

    JPanel p5 = new JPanel();
    p5.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,0,5));
    p5.add(new JTextField("Charisma: "));
    p5.add(chaSpin);

    JPanel p6 = new JPanel();
    p6.add(remainingDisplay);

    JButton confirm = new JButton("Confirm");
    confirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int confirmed = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Is this okay?\nStrength: " + str + "\nDexterity: " + dex + "\nIntelligence: " + intel + "\nConstitution: " + con + "\nCharisma: " + cha, "Confirm distribution", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
            if (confirmed == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    });
    JPanel p7 = new JPanel();
    p7.add(confirm);

    setLayout(new GridLayout(7,1,0,5));
    add(p6);
    add(p1);
    add(p2);
    add(p3);
    add(p4);
    add(p5);
    add(p7);

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    guiStatDistribution2 frame = new guiStatDistribution2();
    frame.setTitle("Distribute your skill points");
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Okay, this is the updated code with spinners in place of buttons. I've just run into two more problems, but after they are resolved the program will be 100% complete. I greatly appreciate the help you've given me so far.

Comment: Basically, two things still need to be done:
1. I'm still struggling to get the JTextField to update the number of remainingPoints as they are used. I have a revalidate command written in, but it doesn't work, probably because I'm still not exactly sure how to properly write revalidate().
2. It seems that when one spinner registers a Change Event, all 5 Listeners register the event instead of just the single spinner that was clicked. This causes the value of remainingPoints to decrease by 5 for every 1 point allocated. I tried creating separate listeners for each spinner, but it didn't work =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using `JSpinners` instead of a `JTextfield` and two `JButtons` for each attribute. This [trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) will tell you everything you need to know. The basic steps are first you need to create number models for each of your spinners, e.g:

```
SpinnerNumberModel strNumberModel = SpinnerNumberModel(1, 1, 20, 1); // value, min, max, step
```

Create the spinner:

```
JSpinner strSpinner = new JSpinner(strNumberModel);
```

Then you need to implement a [ChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ChangeListener.html), something like:

```
strSpinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        str = strNumberModel.getNumber().intValue();
        remainingPoints = remainingPoints - (str + dex + intel + con + cha);
        if (remainingPoints <= 0) {
            // do something
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I actually made another version of the program using spinners before I posted my question. It worked well, but I'm still trying to figure out how to make the variable change with number in the spinner, and change the "remaining points" value change as well.

Comment: okay i started writing the code for the listener and it came up with 3 errors for the str =...
-cannot refer to a non-final variable strPoints inside an inner class defined in another method
-the method getNumber() is undefined for the type SpinnerModel
-cannot refer to a non-final variable str inside an inner class defined in another method

strPoints is the name of the Spinner Model and str is the integer, just for clarification

Comment: Change your SpinnerModel declaration to SpinnerNumberModel and make your skill integers instance variables

Answer (score 1):

I agree with llya, I'd use `JSpinners`.

However, if you like the challange, I'd create an `AttributeAction` that extends from an `AbstractAction` that could take a `JTextField` a modifier and possibly a range

```
public class AttributeAction extends AbstractAction {
    private JTextField field;
    private int modifier;
    private int min;
    private int max;

    public AbstractAttributeAction(String text, JTextField field, int modifier, int max, int min) {
        this.field = field;
        this.modifier = modifier;
        this.max = max;
        this.min = min;
        putValue(NAME, text);
    }

    public void actionPerfomed(ActionEvent evt) {
        try {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(fld.getText());
            value += modifier;
            if (value >= min && value <= max) {
                fld.setText(Integer.toString(value));
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
            // Value was bad
        }
    }
}
```

Then for each button, you simply need to create an appropriate action...

```
JTextField strengthField = new JTextField();
JButton btnPlus = new JButton("+", strengthField, 1, 0, 100);
JButton btnMinus = new JButton("-", strengthField, -1, 0, 100);
```

This, of course, opens up a whole can of worms, like how do you prevent the user from entering non-numeric values, but that's another question ;)

Comment: I haven't learned how to do Abstract Actions yet, so it'd probably be better to use the spinners. Any help with making them change the variables though? I'm still new to writing listeners and I have absolutely no idea what the code should look like.